# What kind of motor can simulate weightlifting? (Difficult to move from locked; can rotate ever so slightly when force is applied)

Tags: motors, gears

Recently, I came across a product that is basically just an exercise mat with two cables for lifting on it. It markets itself as "[digital weight](https://vitruvianform.com/pages/faqs)", and can simulate weight up to 400 pounds.

The way it works is, you stand on the mat, and lift up on handles attached to the cables. The cables themselves are connected to two motors inside the mat. The motors, apparently, read what's happening 40 to 1000 times per second (depending on where you look on the website), and does something (?) with whatever it's measuring. In the end, it determines how much weight you should feel as you lift up.

As you can tell, I'm not sure that I totally understand what's happening, but here is my best guess (only looking at one cable for now):

- Inside the device, a motor is attached to the reel of a winded cable. The cable runs through a slit in the mat up and into the user's hands.
- The machine is constantly reading whether an upward force is applied on the cable. (However this measuring device is also compatible with winding and unwinding the cable onto a reel, see later bullets).
- You (the user) pull up on the cable
- Detecting this upward force, the machine rotates its motor ever so slightly. It rotates more for lighter weights & also provides more rotation for greater measured upward tension applied by the user.
- The cable gains more slack and rises up from the mat
- When force applied by the user is released, rather than simply leaving the extra cable slack against the mat, the motor rotates again, bringing the cable back around the reel. (In some exercises, such as squatting, it would have to do this rewinding in a way that also simulates weight, and to be prepared to unwind again with new upward force)

My question is: How can a machine be used to simulate weightlifting in this way? What is the device that can provide the tension to the microcontroller, in a way that is also compatible with unreeling and reeling up the cable? For e.g. a strain gauge would get in the way of the reeling. What is the motor that can remain locked for up to 400 pounds of force applied when its "Enable" pin is firing?

I'm also tagging this as "gears" in case that's involved.

Comment: a load cell that measures upward force on the winch assembly